# c# wrap model object containing list for MVVM binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding

Lets say I have a model object

```
class ModelClass
{
    public List<Element> eList;

    public void MethodA()
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

I would like to use this object in an MVVM as well. The Viewmodel would then invoke methods like `MethodA` to manipulate the data and the elements in `eList` would be updated. Is there a way to do this without making `eList` an `ObservableCollection`? I'd like to do so in order to use this `ModelClass` in other places as well without too much code polution.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is just as list which notify the view when collection is added, removed & changed. If you want to bind eList to View. Its better to use Observable otherwise after adding you need to notify the view

Answer (score 1):

If we compare **List** and **ObservableCollection** then both are implemented from IList. There isn't much of a difference there. The most difference is  ObservableCollection also implements **INotifyCollectionChanged** interface, which allows WPF to bind to it.

Therefore, if you don't want to use List instead of ObservableCollection in your model class then you need to implement the class with **INotifyCollectionChanged**:

```
class ModelClass:INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public List<Element> eList;// call OnCollectionChanged() when you set/add/remove...the list).

    public void MethodA()
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged Members

    protected void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
            CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    #endregion

}
```